# Looking for a real-time in-app messaging service that also acts as our primary app & web customer support system

Tags: android, ios, chat, sms

We're currently using HelpShift within our app to provide customer support in this manner (live chat style). It's a fine system for the most part, but their support and service are severely lacking so we'd like to move.

Essentially we're looking for a complete Customer Support system that supports all of our customer touch points, and integrates "easily" with them all, but without breaking our budget. While a Google search does reveal options out there, I'm not finding the recommendations I need to move in a direction, considering the time and costs to implement such a service. We've spent thousands on HelpShift over the years just in implementation and update costs, and now we'll likely spend thousands more, so I want to be more education about options folks here have **actually used** and can vouch for before deciding on the right one.

**Some features we'd like to see in a service recommendation are:**

- Ability to seamlessly integrate with existing app and website
- Real-time chat style in-app messaging (think texting)
- Ability to send (from the app and the website) certain data points when customers use the app in order to aid in support (e.g. customer ID, device type, app version, etc)
- A well designed web based administrative CRM system for managing customer communications
- Ability to construct and send push notifications with coupons, app update notifications, etc. based on customer data segments (e.g. target only iOS users with a specific app version installed)

**Some specs:**

- App is built in React Native and supports iOS and Android
- Website is asp.net (custom built, not WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

[Intercom](https://www.intercom.com/) might fit your needs, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is an example implementation, Stack's sites runs on dotnet.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Intercom is on my short list. Have you used them yourself? If so can you vouch for their service, support, and ease of app implementation?

Also, the linked "here" in your reply only leads to a Stack Overflow page. Where is the example of implementation?

Comment: @Dzyner I work with the team that implemented it at Stack, seemed pretty straight forward and we've been pretty happy with it so far. On the page I linked, at the bottom right corner, click circle with the Stack logo, that opens the Intercom integration.